# How to get all users list from Aws Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('cognito-idp')



def lambda_handler():
    response = client.list_users(UserPoolId='ap-south-1_w9By25vrR',AttributesToGet=['email','name'])

    return response
```

I am getting output of a dictionary of all metadata but i want only name,mail only

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Official AWS Code Library** that contains hundreds of these Code examples in the different supported SDKs. This is the doc to refer to when looking for the latest AWS code examples.

[image]

Here is the Python example for this use case.

[List users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/python_3_cognito-identity-provider_code_examples.html#w2496aac13c23b7c25c11)